# How to test async code with angulardart

Tags: unit-testing, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to test a async code with dart.

My logic is:

1. My Service remove a node after a delay.
2. In my test I execute the service and them wait a delay a little more hight to test if the node is removed.

I do this with vanilla dart, but with angular I get the exception:

```
Test failed: Caught [Timer created from sync function.]
```

Then I wrap my test in async and get the follow error:

```
Test failed: Caught [2 active timer(s) are still in the queue.]
```

I create a repo for the tests here: https://github.com/giovannicandido/angulardart-async-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test are executed inside a special zone (see lib/mock/zone.dart).

Inside this zone, new Timer() will create a mock Timer and you need
to call clockTick() to simulate clock ticks.

See test/mock/zone_spec.dart for examples.

Your test should probably look like

```
clockTick(milliseconds: 1150); 
expect(ndom).toBeNull();
```

Comment: Thank you. I think should exists a documentation specific for tests. Test with angular is something that make the developer head very hot :-). I usually go to the source code but it is not trivial.